# All files not being pushed to repository on bitbucket

Tags: php, wordpress, git, sass, bitbucket

I have a repository in Bitbucket, and I pushed changes on my branch in that repo. I had a few php files and a few scss files. The scss files were pushed successfully but the php files were not pushed. I tried committing again but it says nothing to commit and the repo is upto date. Please does anybody know why the php files are not being pushed and rest are working fine.

by the way, I am using wordpress in this project.
Thank you!

[image: as we can see in this image these are the files that has been changed. Indeed these files were changed but there were few php files too that were added in this branch but they are not being shown here and neither being pushed to the repo.]

Comment: There can be various reasons. However, I tend to the fact that the folder in which the php files are located is not followed by git and is possibly listed in `.gitignore` file? If not, we need more information about it...

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have a .gitignore file ? If yes, can you show its content?
2. Try the command: `git status .` and if it shows untracked files then do `git add .`, then you commit your files and push them to your repo.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hey Guys, I already did a git add . but it adds other files except the php files

Comment: Can you share the content of your .gitignore file ?

Comment: @HaiderMansoor Please do not add additional information in comments. Add it to the question itself as an "update". There is an "edit" link below the question for that. _Use it ..._